# Improving method performance java

Tags: java, performance

A better solution?

```
   public String toString(byte[] array) {
        if (array == null)
            return "null";

            StringBuilder  sb = new StringBuilder(256).append('[');
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; ++j) {
                sb.append(array[j]);
                if (j != array.length - 1)
                sb.append(", ");
            }
        return sb.append(']').toString();
    }
```

A better solution? If possible a more rapid solution to perform this method

Comment: What do you want it to do. You're just taking bytes here and writing them out as strings, but I'm not sure what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: This is the same implementation as the Arrays.toString() method. Except that there is one more condition check in the original implementation.

Answer (score 4):

`Arrays.toString()` returns a String representation of the specified array.Maybe this should suffice:

```
String s1 = Arrays.toString(byte);
```

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say it's faster... I would say it's easier. :-)

Comment: when I tried to execute both, this one gave me a significant performance advantage.

Comment: @ambigram_maker It probably is faster. Looking at the source it's almost the same code as in the question minus some unnecessary `array.length` lookups.

Comment: I mean ... this will produce the same result, but it's unclear what the OP is trying to do, exactly. `StringBuilder` doesn't have an `append(byte)` method so there's a widening conversion happening then a String conversion. As for a "performance advantage" I suspect people aren't measuring correctly. At all. Accurate JVM microbenchmarks aren't trivial.

Comment: there best algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

The following line:

```
sb.append(array[j]);
```

is **sort of** expensive, as it involves converting an `int` to a character representation and at the same time keeping track of the working buffer etc.

### An alternative:

If you can live with a result like this:

```
[-123, 123, 002, 000,-022, 127]
```

instead of

```
[-123, 123, 2, 0, -22, 127]
```

Then below method is 2 - 3 times faster on my machine:

```
    public String toString(byte[] array) {
        final char DIGITS[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
        if (array == null) {
            return "null";
        }

        char[] res = new char[(array.length * 5) + 1];

        int abs;
        int pos = 0;
        res[pos++] = '[';
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < 0) {
                abs = - array[i];
                res[pos++] = '-';
            } else {
                abs = array[i];
                res[pos++] = ' ';
            }
            res[pos++] = (abs >= 100 ? '1' : '0');
            int rest = (abs % 100); 
            res[pos++] = DIGITS[rest / 10]; 
            res[pos++] = DIGITS[rest % 10];
            res[pos++] = ',';
        }
        res[res.length - 1] = ']';

        return new String(res);
    }
```

Comment: You have not explained why you want it in a String so fast so i made an assumption that this was ok. I do understand how to code it without the 0. However, it complicates the code, and makes it slower. E.g. the code pre. allocates the array, so it don't need to check boundaries, and don't need to extend it etc.   If you wan't variable length numbers in the output this complicates the logic, therefor making it slower. It's cutting these corners that make above implementation faster than yours.

Comment: conversion of bytes of image to string

Comment: this
`byte[] bytes = {-123, 123, 2, 0, -22, 127};`  

for this
`String mBytes = "[-123, 123, 2, 0, -22, 127]";`

Comment: Need to eliminate 0, with this method and added zeros in this case does not need the 0, help?